# Get data from XPathNodeIterator

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

I have an XPathNodeIterator xpProducts  and it holds an XML like this

```
<estocklevel>0</estocklevel>
<weightingram>0</weightingram>
<unit></unit>
<volume>0</volume>
<discountgroup></discountgroup>
<manufactor>31862244</manufactor>
<deliverydate>1900-01-01T00:00:00</deliverydate>
<dayscreated extra="dayscreated">41489</dayscreated>
```

Now I want to get each nodes data in a string ,I have tried some thing like this

```
 string  strProductID = xpProducts.Current.Select("/manufactor");
```

but it throws an error

```
Error   3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator' to 'string' D:\Projects\20-06-2013-Files\App_Code\DataFetcher.cs    55  28  D:\Projects\20-06-2013-Files\
```

Is it impossible to get string data out of XPathNodeIterator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get string data, you need an XPathNavigator:

```
string strProductID = null;
XPathNavigator navProductID = xpProducts.Current.SelectSingleNode("manufactor");
if(navProductID != null)
{
  strProductID = navProductID.Value;
}
```

I would also recommend using a `foreach` loop rather than `MoveNext()` and `Current`.